# ILogger logs to app insights locally but not on azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, webjob, appinsights

The following code work on my machine locally. That means all log statements are in app insights after some minutes...

When I deploy the application with Publish as Webjob all gets deployed BUT there are no log statement of the triggered webjob although I can see it runs every 5 seconds...

I also tried Thread.Sleep(30000); // 30 seconds...

Why does app insights work locally but not hosted on azure?

Console application .NET 4.7.2:

```
  // Create the DI container.
                IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    
                var appInsightsKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
                Console.WriteLine($"appInsightsKey: {appInsightsKey}");
    
                // Being a regular console app, there is no appsettings.json or configuration providers enabled by default.
                // Hence instrumentation key and any changes to default logging level must be specified here.
                services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                {
                    loggingBuilder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Information);
                    loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights(appInsightsKey);
                }
                );
    
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(appInsightsKey);
                IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                // Obtain logger instance from DI.
                ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
    
                logger.LogWarning("nogger 2: warning");
                logger.LogInformation("nogger2: information");
                logger.LogError("nogger2: error");
    
                Console.WriteLine("This is the end...");
    
                Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
```

**UPDATE**

I am using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService nuget:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service

scroll down for .NET framework console apps!

I have noticed something interesting (the different display of the references...) but maybe it does not make any difference in the end because with both projects the **ILogging** in azure does not work:

**4.7.2** project:

[image: xx]

**4.6.1** project:

[image]

I have also just deployed as Azure Webjob vom Visual Studio with debug mode and still it does not work and I even configured appinsights extra in that deploy dialog but no difference!

Comment: Hi, did you check the configuration on your App Service? Is AppInsights enabled and the connection string properly set?

Comment: As stated in the code I read the appInsightsKey successfully its in the Console log... App Insights must be enabled because it worked from local place... but indeed it is enabled!

Comment: Could it be because locally is no ApplicationInsights.config created? Maybe azure code needs it... I do not remember which process is creating that file maybe when I added any appinsights nuget...

Comment: @HelloWorld which sdk are you using?

Comment: see my UPDATE answer! :-)

Comment: at the moment i use the workaround to use the:             var telemetryClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();
 that instance works on azure logging to appInsights.

Comment: Same issue for me. Did you figure out the solution and where the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting it into a continuous web job...? I had similar issues that got resolved upon switching from triggered to continuous web job...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."